# Can Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() return null?

Tags: .net-core, clr

I saw that the definition of that method is

```
public static Assembly? GetEntryAssembly()
```

Can that method return null in real world scenario?

I'm using .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't mean to be rude, but the method you are asking, is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_Assembly_GetEntryAssembly)? Because it seems that the signature don't have the '?'

Comment: Here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/Assembly.cs#L196